# Traefik point frontend at backend from different provider

Tags: traefik

I need to be able to create a `[file]` provider front-end rule that uses a back-end defined by the `[servicefabric]` provider.

I used the following labels to name my Service Fabric service:

```
<StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="Web1Type">
  <Extensions>
    <Extension Name="Traefik">
      <Labels xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2015/03/fabact-no-schema">
        <Label Key="traefik.servicefabric.groupname">test-site</Label>
        <Label Key="traefik.servicefabric.groupweight">10</Label>
        <Label Key="traefik.frontend.rule.internal">PathPrefixStrip: /test/</Label>
        <Label Key="traefik.frontend.headers.customFrameOptionsValue">DENY</Label>
        <Label Key="traefik.enable">true</Label>
        <Label Key="traefik.frontend.passHostHeader">true</Label>
      </Labels>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
</StatelessServiceType>
```

This way my back-end appears in the Dashboard with the name `test-site`.

Then I have my config file definition that I want to add a hard-coded front-end definition (based on a host name):

```
[frontends]
  [frontends.frontend1]
  backend = "test-site"
  passHostHeader = true
    [frontends.frontend1.routes.public]
    rule = "Host:mytestdomain.localhost"
```

So how do you reference a back-end defined by another provider?

Comment: Any chance you figured this out? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: Afraid not... I just happen to be in that area now, and from my `http://localhost:8889/api/providers/servicefabric/frontends` I can see that they seem to be something like: `frontend-fabric:/MyApplication/MyService` so maybe that...?

Comment: I know traefik v2 has this fixed, but in traefik v1.7 I'm going to try to write the docker port to the host and write in my `file` setup a reference to that port. This should work. I'll report once I give it a go.